# WSSE Security PHP SoapServer- Header not understood

Tags: php, soap-client, soapserver

I have a client call with a WSSE Security Header:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-7BCCD9337425FBA038149772606059420"><wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">NONCE</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2017-06-17T19:01:00.594Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:FUNCTION/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As SoapServer I have a simple one:

```
// the SOAP Server options
$options=array(
    'trace' => true
    , 'cache_wsdl' => 0
    , 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
    , 'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
);

$wsdl = 'http://localhost/index.php?wsdl';

$server = new \SoapServer($wsdl, $options);
$server->setClass('ServerClass');
$server->handle();
$response = ob_get_clean();
echo $response;
```

As soon the property MustUnderstand = 1, then I become from the server the exception: Header not understood.

1. How to understand the header?
2. How to make the WSSE validation on the SoapServer side?

Answer (score 5):

The solution is very tricky! I don't know why is this handled by this way from the SoapServer, but here is the solution:

```
class ServerClass {

    public function Security($data) {
        // ... do nothing
    }

    public function myFunction(){
        // here the body function implementation
    }
}
```

We need to define a function in our class, which is handling the soap request with the name of the header tag, which is holding the soap:mustUnderstand property. The function doesn't need to be implemented in some way.

That's all!

Answer (score 3):

Mutatos' question / answer got me on the right track. I was working outside of a class structure so what worked for me was the following:

```
function Security($data)
{
    $username = $data->UsernameToken->Username;
    $password = $data->UsernameToken->Password;
    //check security credentials here
}

$server = new SoapServer("schema/wsdls/FCI_BookingPullService.wsdl", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$server->addFunction("Security");
$server->handle();
```

Essentially a function with the same name as the SOAP header "<wsse:Security>" (ignore the namespace) is being defined, then telling the server to use that to process the header with the 'addFunction' method.

Not ideal from a scope point of view, if that's an issue, try the class approach.